# Adding minutes to time in a named range?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a range called "Run_Time" and this contains 13:00. I have another range which contains the value 30 (representing minutes).

I wish to combine these two in an IF statement to check whether Now is greater than 13:00 + 30 minutes.

I tried:

```
?DateAdd("n",sheet_Config.Range("Run_Time").value,sheet_Config.Range("Run_Frequency").value)
```

to add the times in the immediate window but it came back with a value containing the year 1899- is this incorrect?

Comment: You can add 30/1440 (where 1440 is the number of minutes in a day).

Comment: Is the 1899 answer expected?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
? Format(sheet_Config.Range("Run_Time").value+(sheet_Config.Range("Run_Frequency").value/1440), "hh:mm:ss")
```

Which will return 13:30. If you only need to compare you could get rid of `Format` function.

Edited- to be precise, to compare you could use this:

```
? Time > (sheet_Config.Range("Run_Time").value+(sheet_Config.Range("Run_Frequency").value/1440))
```